# Releasing an Android Application that uses OSMdroid

Tags: android, gis, geospatial, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I was just wondering if anyone could give me a heads up and any information on where I stand with releasing an Application that uses the OSMdroid open source mapping system. What are the terms of the licensing etc. Should I set up my own map server instead of using the osmdroid mapping server?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "osmdroid mapping server". The server used by osmdroid depends on the *tile provider* given by your specific configuration. This can be the official OSM tile servers, for example. Each tile provider has different terms of use.

The [usage policy of the official OSM tile servers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy) is rather strict because they runs on donated resources. There are [other tile providers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy#Alternative_OpenStreetMap_Tile_Providers) of which some have less strict usage policies. Alternatively you can [set up your own tile server](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) or use a [paid-for tile server](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Commercial_OSM_Software_and_Services).

Comment: Ah I see, so the restrictions lie in the usage of the tile providers then. Where do I stand on charging money for an application that uses OSMdroid?

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase that question? Charging money for a osmdroid-based application should be no problem but mass-downloading of third-party tiles will be a problem.

Comment: ok thats cool, so my best option would be to set up my own tile server for users to download tiles from. Thanks for your help